# How to keep multilingual countries and cities in Database

Tags: database, database-schema, multilingual

I have Database of countries and cities in two different tables, like:

**Countries table**

```
Countries
id    name
__    _______
1     Canada
2     Taiwan
...   .....
N     name
```

**Cities table**

```
Cities
id     name         country_id
___    _________    __________
40     Washington   193
154    Taipei       2
...    ......       ....
N      name         county_id
```

The problem in that it is in **English only**. So I to have cities and countries names in more than 2 languages. I wanted to keep all translations in a single table to have same **ID** for any **country** and **city** being represented in different languages. Should I have to modify my tables into this

**Countries table in 2 languages**

```
Countries
id    name_en   name_kg
__    _______   _______
1     Canada    Канада
2     Taiwan    Тайвань
...   .....     .....
N     name_en   name_kg
```

**Cities table in 2 languages**

```
Cities
id     name_en      name_kg         country_id
___    _________    ________        __________
40     Washington   Вашингтон       193
154    Taipei       Тайпей          2
...    ......       ......          ....
N      name_en      name_kg         county_id
```

So as I told, I may need cities and countries in more than 2 languages. So is it the right way to store my data and where can I get these data? Will be glad for any offer and ideas

Answer (score 0):

You can add a language column based on ISO_639-1_codes on both tables. For example like below. You can do similar structure on cities. Then in all of your queries, you need to know and put the language code in the where condition (where language='EN'). Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
id    name_en   language
__    _______   _______
1     Canada    EN
2     Taiwan    EN
1     加拿大    ZH
2     台灣      ZH

Language_encoding table:
id   code  ISO_lang_name Native_name
1    EN    English       English
2    ZH    Chinese       中文
```

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes